# is there a way to make jubula mapping external object as directory fields?

Tags: eclipse, testing, automated-tests, jubula

I'm using Jubula to automate a JavaFX application. When I click on the browser I can't do an object mapping to select a file or to enter the file path (I think that the new Windows doesn't support JavaFX).

Does anyone have a solution to solve this problem(to map the fields on the image) ?[i can't map these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ06N.png)

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is the operating system's part; it is not written with any of the techniques supported by Jubula.

Your actions are limited to key combinations: https://testing.bredex.de/faqs/can-jubula-test-native-dialogs.html